# Required request part 'file' is not present after form submission in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

After uploading a form that consists of an input type file in Spring, I get an exception that the requested parameter is missing.
This is my form:

```html
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/form}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>
```

And this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
        File destination = new File("directory");
        ImageIO.write(src, "png", destination);
        return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
    } else {
        return "redirect:uploadFailure";
    }
}
```

In pom.xml file I have added the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my Application class I have added the bean(don't have web.xml):

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

But I get

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request part 'file' is not present
```

Why is the file not being uploaded correctly? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your mapping to:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
 public String handleFormUpload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile 
 file)`